# Generics list without generics

Tags: java, generics

I am using a very primitive Java that doesn't have Generics, and also I can't use reflection.

I want to create a generic list so it would be typed safe (i.e. I only have a list that contains Objects and I want to create a list that contains specific object and not a mix).

On the other hand I also don't want to create a different class for each possible list.

Is there any other way to do that without the use of Generics?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. It will be fully run-time solution (no compile-time type checking), but it's worth it (you will get an early crash on first attempt to insert an object with wrong type).

```
public class TypedArrayList extends ArrayList {
    private final Class elementType;

    public TypedList(Class elementType) {
        this.elementType = elementType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object element) {
        // preffered version, use it if it's available on your platform
        // if (!elementType.isInstance(element)) {
        if (!elementType.equals(element.getClass())) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Object of type " + element.getClass() + "passed to List of "+ elementType);
        }
        return super.add(element);
    }

    // override other methods
    // that need type checking
}
```

Usage:

```
TypedArrayList list = new TypedArrayList(String.class);
list.add("works!");
list.add(new Object()); // throws exception
```

You can do the same for LinkedList and any other list type.

Comment: Instead of `equals`, you might want to use [`isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) so it'll also accept child types.

Comment: @IdanArye Do you mean `instanceof`?

Comment: Class.isInstance(Object) (its in the comment in posted code fragment)

Comment: @Azar Not exactly. `instanceof` is a keyword and in order to use it you to write the name of the class inside the code. `isInstance` is a method of `Class` that you can use when you have the class as class object, and does the same thing as `instanceof`.

Comment: @MaciejChałapuk Sorry, didn't notice it. Still - `isInstance` as been around since Java 1.1 so I doubt it's not available on any Java platform that's still being used. Asker's platform is old, but it can't be **that** old...

Comment: @IdanArye Oh okay, my mistake.

Comment: @IdanArye No problem. As for Class.isInstance(Object), there are relatively new platforms that use Java language and don't support reflection (e.g. GWT)